# Printing the IFrame document in IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a Iframe and I am Displaying the PDF inside the Iframe , Now i have to print the Iframe
Document on clicking the Print Button , Its Working fine with Crome , but not working with IE9

frames[0].focus();
frames[0].print();

I am using this code on javascript on button click , its working with Crome but not IE9.
This is Iframe tag:

```
<iframe id="myIframe"  name= "tabsa"   runat="server" src="PDFFilePage.aspx" height="800px"  width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: is your iframe visible , if you put visibility:hidden it will not print in IE9

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the Print Function int the Iframe Page
and call it from the Parent

in the PDFFilePage.aspx page

```
function PrintPDF() {
            Windows.Print();
        }
```

and in the Parent

```
frames[0].PrintPDF()
```

Comment: Hello Tomer ,                                                       I have two pages 1. IframePage.aspx   2. PDFFilePage.aspx , In IframePage , i have two controls "Print" button and Iframe control ,and this Iframe control "src" is set to PDFFilePage.aspx  , In PDFfilePage.aspx  on its pageload i am using Context.Response.ContentType = "application/PDF";
Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); , Please suggest me where i put and call above "PrintPDF"

Comment: you put in in the PDFFilePage.aspx

Comment: you put in in the PDFFilePage.aspx function PrintPDF() {
Windows.Print();} and in the Parent Page IframePage  in the Print Button you call to javascript Function and Put this Code frames[0].PrintPDF()

Comment: When trying above code according to your description , then i am getting this error in javascript in IframePage ,  "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'PrintPDF'"